# How can i draw XYchart in Java using SWT on canvas correctly?

Tags: java, swt, axis, desktop

I need to draw axis and ticks of graph memory java heap. It must resize when canvas is stretches. Drawing happens in method paintControl of PaintListener. Here is loop that draws axises and ticks.

```
ListIterator<GraphData> itr = list.listIterator();
for (int i = client_area.x; i <= client_area.width && step_x > 0 && itr.hasNext(); i += step_x)
{
    String notch_string = returnTime(itr.next());
    int notch_width = a_gc.stringExtent(notch_string).x;
    int cur_beg_x = i - notch_width / 2;
    if(prev_end_x < cur_beg_x)
    {
        a_gc.drawLine(i, client_area.y, i, client_area.height);
        a_gc.drawString(notch_string, cur_beg_x, convertGraphtoLeftBotCorner(client_area.y + NOTCH_LENGTH, a_canvas));
        prev_end_x = cur_beg_x + notch_width;
    } 
}
```

Every step in this loop watches if current tick is not on previous, and if it is, than there are no drawing at all.

Every second new object GraphData adds to list. It has two variables, `y` and `dtime` that determines y of point needed to be drawn and incremention of time. And it happens in parallel thread.

`step_x` calculated in thread and changes every second in dependence of size of list.

```
step_x = canvas.getClientArea().width / list.size();
```

Problem is that after a while due to the fact that `step_x` is getting less than size of list and ticks are disappering the end of graph is not drawing.

Comment: You might want to look at something like [SWT Chart](https://github.com/eclipse/swtchart/wiki) rather than trying to do this yourself.

Comment: @greg-449
First, thanks for this advise, but i can't install this. 



_Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.swtchart.feature,0.12.0.202003130409.
Error reading signed content_
Trying to delete artifact.xml from eclipse, run as administrator and even download this feature are not helping me